After removing a label only some of the messages can be found in All Mail
I read two similar queries, but they don't help me as I can't find 80% of the emails that were under that label.
I wanted to relocate a label that was nested too far down. I did this by first creating a duplicate label higher up in the branch and then moving all the messages from the old label to the new one. 
This seemed okay, as all my emails were under the new label and the old label showed 'Empty'. However, I clicked again on the label to add an email to it, and it showed 'Empty'. I thought it was strange, as I was pretty sure I had deleted it. Anyway, I deleted it again. But, when I looked for the newly created label, I could not find it anymore!
So I researched and found two posts about similar problems. They taught me that the content of a label that has been removed goes to 'All Mail'. However, I could find only 2 emails out of perhaps 15. 
This would have happened after April 19, 2024, so I checked under All Mail for that period but could not find the other missing emails.
 
Now, I'm wondering if the content of a removed label goes under All Mail following the date it was put in it instead of the date it was removed from it.
If this is the case, I will have to search through several thousand emails, as I can't remember what they were called!
Any clarification and help will be much appreciated. 


I read two similar queries, but they don't help me

If you are going to refer to content, include a link so we can know what you are talking about.

They taught me that the content of a label that has been removed goes to 'All Mail'

No. All Mail is not a place messages go to and come from.  It is literally All Your Mail. All your mail with labels, all your mail without labels. All your mail.

Now, I'm wondering if the content of a removed label goes under All Mail following the date it was put in it instead of the date it was removed from it.

Messages are dated and date sorted based on when they were received, if you are the recipient, or sent, if you are the sender. Adding or removing a label from a message does not affect the message's date.
If the messages do not exist in All Mail, you necessarily deleted the messages.  If they exist in All Mail but you can't find them, you will need to adjust your search parameters.
Labels are not folders. They are properties of messages that can be added and removed. The messages themselves don't go anywhere.  Gmail displays a hierarchy of labels that resembles a folder hierarchy but it is not one. Imagine it more like sticky notes or labels on a piece of paper, adding and removing them from a page doesn't relocate it, it simply becomes a page with more or less labels.
